# "Strict MIME Checking Error with 'text/html' MIME Type for 'main.css' on localhost:8080"

Tags: css, express, webpack, sass

I am building a website using Webpack, Sass, Pug, and Express, and I am getting an error in the browser:

```
Strict MIME Checking Error with 'text/html' MIME Type for 'main.css' on localhost:8080
```

I ensured that I linked my `index.scss` into the base.pug view correctly and looked over the Webpack configuration and there is no typo everything looks good.

`npm start` runs the website's back end and front end with only that error but when I run `npm run frontend:build` I get a `module build failed` error. What could be the problem?